# How to Split a Bash Array into Multiple columns in a Markdown table?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to split a Bash array into multiple columns in order to display as a table in a Markdown file.

I have searched around for a quick one-liner to do this using Bash, AWK and other languages. I know about the `column` command, but I can't save the output to a variable or file (`stdout`). I know you can loop the array, extracting values into separate chunks, but there must be an quicker, more efficient way.

- *keywords.md*

```sh
awk
accessibility
bash
behat
c++
cache
d3.js
dates
engineering
elasticsearch
...
```

- *columns.sh*

```sh
local data="$(sort "keywords.md")"     # read contents of file
local data=($data)                     # split contents into an array
local table="||||||\n"                 # create markdown table header
table="${table}|---|---|---|---|---|"
local numColumns=5
# split data into five columns and append to $table variable
```

I am trying to get this result.

```sh
||||||
|---|---|---|---|---|
|awk|bash|c++|d3.js|engineering
|accessibility|behat|cache|dates|elasticsearch
```

[result from column command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRktb.png)

Comment: And why not `|awk|accessibility|bash|behat|c++` and `|cache|d3.js|dates|engineering|elasticsearch` ? Does the order matter? It would be just `xargs printf "|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n"`.

Comment: The more efficient way to do this is to just do it all in awk but you need to explain the algorithm used to produce that output as it's not clear what the output would be if you had more than 25 rows of input. Even how to handle more than 10 input rows isn't clear (would output row 1 start with input rows 1 3 5 as above or 1 4 7 or something else)?

Comment: My thinking was, that you would determine the size of the columns (total/5), extract values up to that number for the first, second, third, fourth column, and then fill whatever values are left in the last column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the general approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numCols = (numCols ? numCols : 5)
    OFS = "|"
}
{
    colNr = (NR - 1) % numCols + 1
    if ( colNr == 1 ) {
        numRows++
    }
    vals[numRows,colNr] = $0
}
END {
    hdr2 = OFS
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        hdr2 = hdr2 "---" OFS
    }
    hdr1 = hdr2
    gsub(/-/,"",hdr1)
    print hdr1 ORS hdr2

    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        printf "|"
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            val = vals[rowNr,colNr]
            printf "%s%s", val, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
||||||
|---|---|---|---|---|
|awk|accessibility|bash|behat|c++
|cache|d3.js|dates|engineering|elasticsearch
```

but it obviously doesn't output the columns in the order you asked for in your question as I don't understand how you arrive at that order.

Comment: This works, thanks. I was really trying to re-implement the result from the `column` command, determining the size of columns, extracting values up to that size and filling the last column with the remaining values.

Comment: You're welcome. This question doesn't capture that at all so post a new question describing that so we can help you with it. And be aware that a shell is NOT a tool to manipulate text, it's a tool to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The guys who invented shell also invented awk as the general purpose tool for shell to call when manipulating text was required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl version that prints out the values going down by column like in your sample desired output:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my $ncolumns = 5;

# Read the list of values.
my @data;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  push @data, $_;
}

# Partition the data up into rows, added down by column
my @columns;
my $nrows = @data / $ncolumns;
#@data = sort { $a cmp $b } @data;
while (@data) {
  my @c = splice @data, 0, $nrows;
  for my $n (0 .. $#c) {
    push @{$columns[$n]}, $c[$n];
  }
}

# And print them out
say '|' x $ncolumns;
say '|', join('|', ('---') x $ncolumns), '|';
for my $r (0 .. $nrows - 1) {
  my @row;
  for my $c (0 .. $ncolumns - 1) {
    my $item = $columns[$r]->[$c];
    push @row, $item if defined $item;
  }
  push @row, ('')x$ncolumns;
  say '|', join('|', @row[0 .. $ncolumns - 1]);
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./table.pl keywords.md
|||||
|---|---|---|---|---|
|awk|bash|c++|d3.js|engineering
|accessibility|behat|cache|dates|elasticsearch
```